# why Blum-Micali algorithm is deterministic algorithm

Tags: deterministic-encryption

Can anyone give me the answer of the following question.

Justify why Blum-Micali algorithm is deterministic algorithm ?

Comment: I know about deterministic, my question is why Blum-Micali algorithm is deterministic algorithm ?

Comment: Blum-Micali algorithm cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator

Answer (score 0):

Blum-Micali algorithm is is a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator.

Let $p$ be a prime, and $g$ is a primitive root mod $p$ and $x_0$ is the seed. Then, let $x_{i+1} = g^{x_i}\ \bmod{\ p} $.

The i-th output is $$ 1 \text{ if } x_i<(p−1)/2. $$ 
$$ 0 \text{ Otherwise}$$

Since whenever you started from the same seed, you will get the same results, so it is deterministic. There is no randomness in the calculations.